# Invalid SQLAlchemy Model when automapping database to graphene

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphene-python

I'm trying to work with graphene-sqlalchemy on an existing database I'm automapping.

database automapping:

```
engine = create_engine(" blablabla", convert_unicode=True)

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, generate_relationship=_gen_relationship, name_for_scalar_relationship = name_for_scalar_relationship, classname_for_table=camelize_classname, name_for_collection_relationship=pluralize_collection)

Buyer = Base.classes.Buyer

Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

schema :

```
import graphene
import json
from graphene import relay
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyConnectionField, SQLAlchemyObjectType

from database import Buyer as BuyerModel

class Buyer(SQLAlchemyObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = BuyerModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    all_buyers = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Buyer)

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Produces the error :

```
AssertionError: You need to pass a valid SQLAlchemy Model in Buyer.Meta, received "<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.Buyer'>".
```

Comment: I see nothing fundamentally wrong with your code. Have you checked that you can actually use the SQLAlchemy class outside of Graphene?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. If you ever found a solution...please do share!